# Where clause with INNER JOIN - Acts on subset or on original table?

Tags: mysql

Given this query:

```
SELECT `promotions`.* 
FROM `promotions` 
    INNER JOIN `orders_promotions` ON `promotions`.`id` = `orders_promotions`.`promotion_id` 
WHERE `orders_promotions`.`order_id` = 3
AND `promotions`.`code` = 'blablabla'
```

I wonder if the last `WHERE` (`` WHERE `promotions`.`code` = 'blablabla' ``) statement acts against the WHOLE `promotions` table, or acts against the set returned by the `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: why are there 2 where clauses? This query is semantically incorrect.

Comment: Sebas, sorry. It should be an AND.

Comment: Regardless of if the WHERE clause is before or after the join, you should get the same results.  For the sake of efficiency, it should handle the WHERE first to reduce the amount of work for the INNER JOIN.

Comment: This is a decision that depends on the opinion the query optimizer has about your query. It varies from query to query, and the `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for mysql will give you your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Order of operation by which SQL queries gets executed is as below

```
FROM clause
JOIN clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause
```

As you can see `WHERE` comes after the `JOIN` operation has performed; that says that in your above posted query `WHERE` conditions will be acted against the result set obtained from the JOIN operation.

You can change your query and include the condition in `JOIN ON` clause to get it filtered before it gets to `WHERE` clause like

```
SELECT `promotions`.* 
FROM `promotions` 
INNER JOIN `orders_promotions` 
ON `promotions`.`id` = `orders_promotions`.`promotion_id` 
AND `orders_promotions`.`order_id` = 3
WHERE `promotions`.`code` = 'blablabla'
```

You may want to read [This Article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm)

Comment: In terms of performance this is exactly the same, query optimizer will use the where clause filters during the join phase to calculate the intermediate resultsets right away. Explain plans can prove you this point.

Comment: yes may be and optimizer is all together a separate story which I am not bringing it here. My answer exactly points to what OP has asked; i.e, how the `WHERE` acts against the result set.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, the where clause is included in the join predicate if judged necessary. What you state is true in older versions of mainstream rdbms though, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Can you back your claim?

Comment: Yes, even though how things are processed internally is rather a blackbox, the algorithm used to compute the joins is published when using the `EXPLAIN` command, at least for mysql and oracle. In the latter case, you will see in that article here (http://structureddata.org/2008/02/18/ansi-outer-joins-and-lateral-views/) that the explain plans of query A and B are strictly identical even though the WHERE clause has been moved to the ON clause. Please disregard the main outer join topic of the article which is not our concern right now.

Comment: As far as I can tell, everything is a resultset now. Only the HAVING clause will have a different processing schedule I believe (I have nothing to back it up though)

Comment: Sebas, from beginning you are just talking about optimizer. I am not concerned about what optimizer will do and neither is it for MySQL/Oracle. What I have said is plain basic DBMS concept which applies to all and irrespective of optimizer.

Comment: But there's no such thing as `Order of operation by which SQL queries gets executed` else than what the optimizer tells you. The query you provide is completely identical in terms of execution and filter phases. It would be different in case of OUTER join though, but as I said it is off-topic